# Annotation class for Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I looking for a class for making annotations in my Unity3D Scene.
I don't know if he have already a class for that, i searched it, but i have found nothing.

Below, you can find the annotation make in WPF.

[image: Annotation with in WPF]

Answer (score 1):

What about adding GUI.Label to your objects?

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Label.html

Also, check out this reference:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjectLabel

Let me know if you have any further questions or a specific example you want to get working.